# Row Normalization in Kettle (PDI)

Tags: transformation, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to achieve the below logic using pentaho.The Time column in the input is variable so have to be dynamic enough to accommodate this.Please guide me how to achieve this in pentaho.

```
Input:-
----------------------
ID    |ID2  |ID3|Time 
----------------------
4001  |1003 |TN |1398364200,1398450600,1398537000,1398623400,1398709800,1398796200
---------------------


Output:-
----------------------------
ID    |ID2  |ID3|  Time 
----------------------------
4001  |1003 |TN |1398364200
4001  |1003 |TN |1398450600
4001  |1003 |TN |1398537000
4001  |1003 |TN |1398623400
4001  |1003 |TN |1398709800
4001  |1003 |TN |1398796200
----------------------------
```

**My Design**

Table-->Java Script(For calculating the Time Intervals)-->Split Rows-->Row Normalizer.

I see that the design above is useful only when the no of Time intervals are fixed and not so useful for dynamic data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your questions will be answered more quickly if you include your attempts at the solution that you have achieved so far. Not including any source code at all would require others to solve your task completely without any contribution from your side. That's not the idea behind StackOverflow.

Comment: Not sure to understand. In order to get the output you showed, there's no need of row normalizer. You can stop at "split field to rows" step. Besides, please elaborate "not so useful for dynamic data". In fact you will always get as many rows as delimiter char + 1.

Comment: hi andtorg..thanks for pointing out ..I have been using the Split fields for doing this.switched to "split field to rows" it worked.

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question to offically close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

andtorg..thanks for pointing out ..I have been using the Split fields for doing this.switched to "split field to rows" it worked.